# Does cloudflare provide anti-DDoS protection for dedicated servers?

Tags: ddos, cloudflare, dedicated-server

I have a dedicated server that sometimes gets DDoS attacked. Does Cloudflare give you protection for dedicated servers or is it for websites only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does Cloudflare give you protection for dedicated servers or is it for websites only?

Cloudflare only provides DDOS protection for services that are:

- DDNS protected on it's services (i.e. things that are proxied through them)

This means that the raw IP and any service that you can not proxy through them obviously can not be DDOS protected. Note that HTTPS does not necessarily mean a website.